# Why does the compiler not reserve enough space on the stack?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, linker, stack, segmentation-fault

I have a C++ class `Matrix22` with an array and a default constructor:

```
class Matrix22{
  /* something more */
  double mat[2][2];
  Matrix22(){
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
      for(int j=0; j<2; j++)
        mat[i][j] = i==j ? 1.0 : 0.0;
  }
};
```

I used it in my program and got a segmentation fault. As the rest was quite difficult and complicated I wrote a simple test routine, that just calls `Matrix22()`. No more seg fault.

I then ran `gdb` to debug the problem. If I call the constructor from the separate test routine, `gcc` reserves some memory for the member `mat`. I can navigate through the stack and see the return address some bytes after the array.

In the main program the compiler does not reserve enough space. The first element (`mat[0][0]`) gets written but any futher write just overwrites the next stack frame. I can also verify that as before the constructor the command `bt`returns a correct backtrace, where after the critical assignment the backtrace is corrupted.

So my question is: Why does in one case the compiler (or the linker?) reserve not enough space for the array, while in the other case that is not happening?

PS: Both "test cases" are compiled with the same compiler and flags and alsolinked against the same object files.

edit:

Here is the "simple" test case that works without seg fault:

```
void test_Matrix22()
{
  Framework::Math::Matrix22 matrix;
}
```

The code with creates a seg fault is in the class `ModuleShaddower` (intermixed header and implementation):

```
class ModuleShaddower{
    public:
        ModuleShaddower(PVModule& module, const EnvironmentalSetup& setup, const Position& position);
    private:
        Matrix22 rotMatrix90;
};

ModuleShaddower::ModuleShaddower(PVModule& module, const EnvironmentalSetup& setup, const Position& position)
  : module (module), position(position), setup(setup), logger(LoggerFactory::getLoggerInstance())
{
    double mat[][2] = {{0, -1},{1, 0}}; // This line will never be reached
    rotMatrix90 = Matrix22(mat);
}
```

As you see, it is quite from within the rest. I will maybe try to extract the problematic code but I think this won't help much.

Comment: Can you provide the complete test-case?  (the one that fails)

Comment: What Oli said: show us how you are using the class.

Comment: The short test is no problem. The long version has several thousand lines of code. I'll try to give a part of it

Comment: Generally insufficient stack space/stack overflow conditions are caused by recursions that have bad (or missing) termination conditions.  There is nothing in the code posted that should cause stack problems--indeed, that constructor likely doesn't require any stack at all.

Comment: It is NO stack overflow in the sense that the memory is running out. This constructor overwrites (valid) momory on the stack that is used by another stack frame. Therefore the stack gets corrupted and later the program crashes as it trys to jump somewhere it cannot jump to (if the relevant frame is done and should exit).

Comment: Keep simplifying your code until the bug disappears, then undo the last change. At that point, you'll have a minimal example; it will have no more than 50 lines. If you still can't figure it out, post it here.

Comment: Can it be a lib problem? I have two files `Shaddower.o` in an static archive containing different code. I renamed one (due to linker problems) and the seg fault was left. Can it be the case that the wrong code has been executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to the fact that two object files in different locations had the same name. In the resulting static library, that was created from that object code, sometimes the wrong file gets replaced (both were called `Shaddower.o`). As I renamed one of the files all went well and no more errors.

I do not know the exact origin of this problem but it is solvable like that.

Answer (score 0):

If your ModuleShaddower contructor code is not getting reached (as per you code comment) then something in your constructor initialization list (related to contructuction of module, possition etc) is causing the problem.

Comment: I would agree with you. But if I go through with the debugger, I enter the constructor Matrix22(). At the beginning the stack is all right (checked via `bt`). After the loops have gone through, the stack is corrupted. So for me it's clear that the problematic code is within the Matrix22() constructor. PS: The other parameters are all references. They are created outside without problems. If theys were the problem, the whole problem should happen at another position in my opinion or am I wrong?